# Yii2 get column from junction table and use in gridview

Tags: activerecord, yii2

Part of my schema is a pictured:[image]

The junction table maps which items are in which category, with the "featured" column marking the item as featured in that category.

What I need to do is get a list of all items in a specific category, including the "featured" attribute from the junction table and pass that data for display into a gridview.

I have created a model for the `category_item` table and tried to implement the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28784322/2271704) but how do I access and pass the data into the gridview?

**Category Model**

```
public function getCategoryItems()
{
    return $this->hasMany(CategoryItem::className(), ['category_id' => 'id']);
}

public function getItems()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Item::className(), ['id' => 'item_id'])->viaTable('{{%category_item}}', ['category_id' => 'id']);
}
```

**CategorySearch Model**

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = Category::find()->with('items')->with('categoryItems');

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'id' => $this->id,
        'type' => $this->type,
    ]);

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'title', $this->title])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'description', $this->description]);

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

**Item Model**

```
public function getItemCategories()
{
    return $this->hasMany(CategoryItem::className(), ['item_id' => 'id']);
}

public function getCategories()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::className(), ['id' => 'category_id'])->viaTable('{{%category_item}}', ['item_id' => 'id']);
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function actionCategory($id = null)
{
    if($id == null) {
        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => Category::find()->all(),
        ]);

        return $this->render('category', [
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    } else {

        $category = Category::findOne($id);

        if($category) {
            $searchModel = new CategorySearch();

            $itemsDataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
                'query' =>  $searchModel->search(['CategorySearch'=>['id'=>$id]]),
            ]);

            return $this->render('editCategory', [
                'itemsDataProvider' => $itemsDataProvider
                'model' => $category,
            ]);
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
        }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2>Items</h2>
        <?= GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $itemsDataProvider,
            'columns' => [

                'id',
                'name',
                'categoryItems.id',
                [
                    'attribute' => 'items.description',
                    'format' => 'html',
                    'value' => 'description',
                ],
                [
                    'label'=>'Highlights',
                    'format'=>'raw',
                    'value'=>function($data) use ($model) {
                        if(TagFeaturedItem::find()->where(['item_id'=>$data->id, 'tag_id'=>$model->id])->all()) {
                            return Html::a('Remove as Highlighted', ['/highlights/category/'.$model->id.'/remove/'.$data->id], ['class'=>'btn btn-xs btn-danger']);
                        } else {
                            return Html::a('Add as Highlighted',['/highlights/category/'.$model->id.'/add/'.$data->id], ['class'=>'btn btn-xs btn-primary']);
                        }
                    },
                ],
            ],
        ]); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

In general the view file is a mix and match from trying to find a solution.
The TagFeaturedItem model is from a previous version of the view, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30411088/2271704)

Comment: Could you also show us the view file?

Comment: Thanks. And the whole thing doesn't causes error? You just want to access the feature flag? I see another class TagFeaturedItem...

Comment: Yes, I can get the category items via the `$category->items` relation but the `featured` column is of course missing.

Comment: Ah, sorry, to hard for me... Wondering why `'categoryItems.id`' and `'items.description'` works. And why does `new ActiveDataProvider(['query' =>  $searchModel->search(['CategorySearch'=>['id'=>$id]]),]);` work. Shoudn't query be a QueryInterface implementation?

Comment: I'd like to start from a clean slate on this one because I myself have been mixed up trying to following all the articles and advice doing the rounds on the internet.
Documentation is sparse/non-existent for this type of problem, so right now I'm looking for just a solution, I can throw away any code written up till now and implement something that works.

Comment: I think that's a good idea. Personally, I'd consider to have an ItemController with all common actions as well. At least, I'd say that the table structure is optimal.

Comment: The question now is what do I do from here on! I've run out of ideas.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78894/discussion-between-robsch-and-jimmy).

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion there may be some design flaws in your project that I will not explore; I will zero in on the question of how to get the related data into the gridview.

You can create a custom column in the gridview and then get the related data, you would add something like this to your gridview column array:

```
    [
            'label'=>'featured',
            'format'=>'raw',
            'value'=>function($data)
            {
                $categories = $data->categories; 

                $content = "";
                foreach($categories as $category)
                    $content .= $category->title."<br/>";

                return $content;
            }
    ],
```

Note that `$data` represents the model returned by the data provider, in the above example from your Item Model.

Comment: I'd be very interested in learning what design flaws there might be (to fix and learn from), please elaborate.
Also it's not getting the related data that's troublesome, it's getting and displaying the "featured" column from the join table..

Comment: @jimmy Your controller actionCategory is a bit strange. At least I haven't seen it this way until now. Usually, one has an actionIndex and actionUpdate method. You have combined them into one action, as it seems.

Comment: I have it this way to achieve a flatter url structure. My url's should be something like `highlights/category` which should map to the classic `category/index`, `highlights/category/1` which should map to something like `category/update/1`. But I also have `highlights/keyword`. The thing is, in this project and for the specific client, categories/keywords are the same thing (programmatically) and have the same actions. So I merged them into one table where a flag differentiates type.

Comment: @jimmy And also you are using the CategorySearch when you already have a certain category...

Comment: @jimmy I think usually you would solve this with urlManager rules.

Comment: @robsch I started out using the url manager but the routes and controllers ended up too unwieldy. For each category and keyword you have the option to add/delete highlighted items, and people. So I moved everything to a `highlights` controller and ended up with something like the above.
As for the CategorySearch, that is a few iterations trying to find a solution to the "featured" column.
For a bit of history as to why it's a flag see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30411088/combine-data-from-two-different-junction-tables#comment48910534_30411088

Comment: Helpful answer but should be `$content .= $category->title."<br/>";` or else you get a number back.